# Setting each executor memory differently (Spark Standalone)

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

In our cluster, datanodes doesn't have same hardware specs. For example:

```
dnode1 -> 4  GB RAM 
dnode2 -> 15 GB RAM
dnode3 -> 30 GB RAM
```

When submitting a spark job, to use every datanode I must set spark.executor.memory to some value that every datanode can afford. However I wonder if there is a way to set memory usage of each executor processes independently? For example:

```
Executor in dnode1 will use around 4 GB RAM
Executor in dnode2 will use around 15 GB RAM
Executor in dnode3 will use around 30 GB RAM
```

Comment: Executors are the same size for each process (specified by the application). What you need is the same number of cores/memory available to each worker and then choose how many workers on each node (which could be tailored to the individual workers).

Comment: How do you choose the number of executors that will be in each worker node?

Comment: Each worker process will have one executor per app. But your slave nodes can run more than one worker.